# SQL Server Query to find records with exact numbers in string

Tags: sql-server, pattern-matching

I am querying against a column that has data as follows

```
Winners - 1,2,3,4,5,6,21,24 / 2,8,11,21,22,24 / 12,13,15,16 / 12,13,15,21,24
Winners - 2,5 / 2,5 / 1,6,11,12,22,24 / 1,11,12,22,24
Winners - 1,3,5 / 1,3,5 / 4,8,11 / 2,12,14,16,21
```

How could I find ones with 2 or 6 in any of the four blocks I have?
I currently have a query as follows

```
select * from scores where results like 'Winners - %[2,6]%/%[2,6]%/%[2,6]%/%[2,6]%'
```

But that also returns ones that match 21, 12, 26, 16 and so on. I want to match exactly 2 or exactly 6.

Comment: try removing the `,`

Comment: @mainstreetmark how will that help?

Comment: `[2,6]` matches a `2`, a `,` or a `6`.   `/\D[26]\D/` would be a regexpr that matches 2's and 6's, but not 12's.  Try `WHERE scores REGEXP '[[:<:]][26][[:>:]]'`.  I haven't tried this, though.

Comment: well, throwing syntax error at REGEXP. I am on SQL Server 2008 if that helps.

Comment: I have a working example but its based on multiple `LIKE` and `OR`'s I am thinking there must be a better way.

Comment: `WHERE results  Like '% 2%' OR results  Like '% 6%' OR results   Like '%,2 %' OR results  Like '%,6 %' OR results  Like '%,2,%' OR results  Like '%,2' OR results   Like '%,6'`  If it has to have the word winners too just put the above in brackers and add `AND results like 'Winners - %'`

Answer (score 0):

I am sure there is a better way I don't know about but here are two solutions

```
SELECT *
FROM scores 
WHERE 
((REPLACE(REPLACE(result,'Winners - ', ','), ' / ', ',') + ',') LIKE '%,2,%' 
OR (REPLACE(REPLACE(result,'Winners - ', ','), ' / ', ',') + ',') LIKE '%,6,%')
AND  result LIKE 'Winners - %'



SELECT *
FROM scores     
WHERE (result Like '% 2%' OR result Like '% 6%' OR result  Like '%,2 %' 
 OR result Like '%,6 %' OR result Like '%,2,%' OR result  Like '%,2' OR result  Like '%,6')
AND result LIKE 'Winners - %'
```